# Creating Dynamic Resource pool from Hive CLI

Tags: hive, resources, command-line-interface, pool

Can we create dynamic resource pools on hive using CLI?
I want the Hive Scripts to run with Xmemory and X Cores each time it runs. Each Script will have a different requirement for memory and Cores which is why i dont want to create pre-defined pools.

Comment: Hive CLI is a fat client. You fire a JVM with the query processor, run 1..N commands or queries sequentially (each query spawning an external YARN job), then stop the JVM. What kind of "resource pool" do you expect to build with that?!